# Find the opposite of a direction angle (360 degrees) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

The following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319615/how-to-calculate-opposite-direction-angle shows the formula for doing this. How would I write this: `(α+180) mod 360` in javascript. (a is a variable)

Answer (score 11):

You should use the `%` operator:

```js
var angle = 210;
var oppositeAngle = (angle + 180) % 360;
console.log(oppositeAngle);
```